# Trying to display the contents of a textbox within a dynamic table ONLY after the enter key has been pressed

Tags: jquery

The problem I have when the following code executes, it will first display the original contents of the textbox, then each set of keys that I pressed up until hitting 'Enter'.  So if the textbox originally contained 'Ice Cream - Pierre's Chocolate Chip' and I click in the textbox to get focus and replace it with 'Tea', I will get 4 alert boxes, each with the following content:

1. Ice Cream - Pierre's Chocolate Chip
2. T
3. Te
4. Tea

And then if I click on a different row and do something else, I will get the original 4 alert boxes from before and then the new ones...it keeps stacking and I don't know why?

Here is some code from my .cs file - note the "OnKeyPress" attribute I added:

```
        public TCell(String celltext,String strTextBox,String strName)
        {
            int iWidth = 0;
            int intRandom =
            iWidth = Convert.ToInt32(strTextBox);
            tblCell = new TableCell();
            TextBox txtItem = new TextBox();
            txtItem.ID = strName;
            txtItem.Text = celltext;
            txtItem.Width = iWidth;
            txtItem.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            txtItem.CssClass = "cssAdjust trans";
            txtItem.Style.Add("padding", "0px 5px 0px 5px");
            txtItem.Attributes.Add("onKeyPress","captureTable(this.value);");
            txtItem.Attributes.Add("onFocus", "javascript:this.select();");
            tblCell.Controls.Add(txtItem);
        }
```

And then here is the function where I am displaying once the enter key is pressed:

```
 function captureTable(strValue) 
 {
     $(document).keypress(function (e) {
         if (e.which == 13) // Enter has been pressed.
         {
             e.preventDefault();
             document.getElementById("<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>").value = strValue;
             alert(strValue);
         }
     });
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.  I had this working using "window.event" but that locks me into IE from what I read and I am trying to use JQuery for this.

(UPDATE):

Ok, I used the code provided by kmb385 below, but I think I'm missing something still.  I don't get any alerts appearing, so I set a breakpoint at the '$(".txtHook").keypress(function(e){' line and it doesn't reach it during key entry inside of the table text box, including the enter key.

Here is where the code resides within the default.apsx page:

```
 <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">

  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".txtHook").keypress(function(e){ 
         if (e.which == 13) // Enter has been pressed.
         {
             e.preventDefault();
             document.getElementById("<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>").value = $(this).val(); 
             alert(strValue);
         }
     });
  });
```

My inclusion of JQuery is within the body tag of the site's master page:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
```

(FINAL UPDATE:)

Turns out my inclusion of JQuery was incorrect.  I moved it to the head tag of the master page and changed the code to read:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

After that, the code provided my kmb385 started to work :)

Comment: do you want to capture when they hit the enter key while the input field has focuse or just whenever they hit the enter key?

Comment: Whichever textbox has focus at the time the enter key is pressed.  If they hit enter and focus is on a radio button selection they just made, I would like for that to be ignored. My screen is comprised of 2 drop down lists, a table, 3 radio buttons, and various labels displaying information based on the selected row in my table.  I was using the alerts to test my logic for capturing contents that were keyed into the textboxes.  Thanks.

Comment: ok, this helps me answer your question.

Comment: Great!  Thank you, thank you!  I added more to my comment above just to paint a better picture of my layout if that helps in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original javascript code was binding an anonymous function to the keypress event on the document, each time a key was pressed in an input you created.  This resulted in multiple functions being fired each time a key was pressed anywhere on the document/page. I removed your binding to the onKeyPress event in the .cs file.  Also in the cs file I added a class attribute to the textbox so I could hook into it in jquery.

In the Javascript I use the class selector in jquery to bind a function to the keypress event of each input.  The function gets the value of the input and assigns it to the hidden input.  There may be issues with this code because I'm not familiar with .net, if there is let me know and we can work through them.  I am skeptical of the following selector but I'm guessing its a .net thing.

> document.getElementById("<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>").value

```
public TCell(String celltext,String strTextBox,String strName)
{
    int iWidth = 0;
    int intRandom =
    iWidth = Convert.ToInt32(strTextBox);
    tblCell = new TableCell();
    TextBox txtItem = new TextBox();
    txtItem.ID = strName;
    txtItem.Text = celltext;
    txtItem.Width = iWidth;
    txtItem.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    txtItem.CssClass = "txtHook cssAdjust trans";
    txtItem.Style.Add("padding", "0px 5px 0px 5px");
    txtItem.Attributes.Add("onFocus", "javascript:this.select();");
    tblCell.Controls.Add(txtItem);
}
```

Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".txtHook").keypress(function(e){
            if (e.which == 13) // Enter has been pressed.
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                document.getElementById("<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>").value = $(this).val();
                alert(strValue);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Ok, I will give this a go shortly and let you know.  Thank you for the quick response, much appreciated (especially the explanation to why this was behaving the way it was).

Comment: Tried to post more code but it didn't let me.  I added to my original post above - this didn't work, but I explain in detail (with additional code) above:

Comment: Turns out my inclusion code for JQuery was incorrect.  Once I put '<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>' in the head tag of my master page, your code started to work :)  Thanks again for your help, I'm full steam ahead.